# SMTP Mail Server sending mail not work

Tags: php, email, smtp

i am trying to send mail via smtp from `gmail`

my php code is

```
<?php
$body             = 'test body';
$to = "test_useremail@example.org";
$from = 'mytestmail@gmail.com';
$fName = 'first name';
$lName = 'last name';
$subject =  'my subject';
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
  //  $body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com"; // SMTP server example
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for    testing)
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Port       = 587;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "mytestmail@gmail.com"; // SMTP account username example
$mail->Password   = "password";
$mail->SetFrom($from, $fName.' '.$lName);
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->AddAddress($to, "Support Team");
$mail->MsgHTML($body);

if(!$mail->Send()) {
     echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
exit;
}
?>
```

its give me this error ::

```
SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Permission denied (13)
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
```

i don't know what is problem ?

Comment: try `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';` 

are you using correct credentials for gmail?

Comment: added `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';` but not working

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code it is working for me

```
  <HTML>
  <body>
  MAIL SETTING for Iseries<br>
  Define a real name of your mail Server<br>
  <center>
  SMTP = mail.zend.com </center>
  <br>
  Define a real name of your mail Server<br>
  <center>
  smtp_port = 25</center>
  <br>
  Define an any address you want<br>
  <center>
  sendmail_from = shlomo@zend.com</center><br>
  </body>


  <?php
  // Using the ini_set()
  ini_set("SMTP", "mail.zend.com");
  ini_set("sendmail_from", "shlomo@zend.com");
  //ini_set("smtp_port", "25");

 // The message
  $message = "The mail message was sent with the following mail setting:\r\nSMTP = mail.zend.com\r\nsmtp_port = 25\r\nsendmail_from = YourMail@address.com";

// Send
$headers = "From: shlomo@zend.com";

mail('shlomo@zend.com', 'My Subject', $message, $headers);

echo "Check your email now….<BR>";?>
</HTML>
```

Just change your credential 
Actual link http://kb.zend.com/smtp-mail-the-php-mail-function-for-iseries/#.Uqa9NY1Mhno

Answer (score 0):

```
$subject = "This is subject testing1";
$mail = new PHPMailer();    
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML    
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 465;                   // set the SMTP port 
$mail->From       = '';
$mail->FromName   = "";
$mail->Subject    = $subject;
$mail->Body       = "this is html body";           //HTML Body
$emailId='';
```

Answer (score 0):

> SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Permission denied (13)

This indicates that your php script is not allowed to open the connection. Check the security settings of this server (SELinux etc)

Answer (score 0):

Are u working in localhost or hosted in some server ?

By default, from localhost we can't send mails, because SMTP is not available.

Comment: i am not working in `localhost` i am working on live website and live webserver

Comment: OK, Check the following links; you may get some solution; i think you need to execute these commands from server.
http://gistpages.com/2013/09/14/phpmailer_smtp_error_failed_to_connect_to_server_permission_denied_13_fix
http://blog.innovsystems.com/php/smtp-error-failed-connect-server-permission-denied-13